# How do I write a function inside a ArgMin

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve this

```
ArgMin[NIntegrate[(Tanh[x] - Erf[x/a])^2, {x, -5, 5}], a]
```

and it does not work, what is the correct way to do this?

```
"The integrand (-Erf[x/a]+Tanh[x])^2 has evaluated to non-numerical \
values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries \
{{-5,0.}}."
```

Comment: `NIntegrate` is for numerical solution, you will get error with symbol `a` in the argument of `NIntegrate`

Comment: if I try to ArgMin x^2 , it has no problem substituting x inside x^2 . How do I make mathematica do this

Comment: @grdgfgr Have you tried `Integrate` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that during the evaluation process it attempts to numerically integrate using the symbol `a`. That is the source of the warning message.

However, if you persist (and ignore the warning), `ArgMin` will eventually switch over to using numerical values and output the correct value.

```
ArgMin[{NIntegrate[(Tanh[x] - Erf[x/a])^2, {x, -5, 5}], 
  0.5 <= a <= 2.0}, a]

1.20136
```

You can validate this by plotting the numerical integration over a range of `a` values.

```
Plot[NIntegrate[(Tanh[x] - Erf[x/a])^2, {x, -5, 5}], {a, 0.4, 2.0}, 
 PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 0.3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to entirely eliminate the warning define a function that requires a numeric argument

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(Tanh[x] - Erf[x/a])^2, {x, -5, 5}]
```

and then run `ArgMin`.

```
ArgMin[{f[a], 0.5 <= a <= 2.0}, a]
(* 1.20136 *)
```

This issue has been answered previously but I didn't have time to locate it.